# How to write an observable collection to a txt file?

Tags: c#, save, observablecollection, streamwriter, writetofile

Whats the best way to write an observable collection to a txt file? I currently have the following

```
public ObservableCollection<Account> SavedActionList = new ObservableCollection<Account>();   
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("SavedAccounts.txt")) 
        {
            foreach (Account item in SavedActionList)
            {
                file.WriteLine(item.ToString()); //doesn't work
            }
            file.Close();
        }
```

I'm not sure why it won't write to the file. Any ideas?

Comment: That should create some output - when you say "doesn't work", what's different/wrong compared to your expectations?

Comment: It simply doesn't work. I'm really confused as to why, which is why I posted the question. I tested it by inserting a file.WriteLine("Hello") before the file.Close() and when i run the program and check the file all it will have in it is "Hello"

Comment: Are you sure there are actually items in your collection?  If you step through, does it ever step into the file.WriteLine step?  That will be skipped if there are no items int he collection...

Comment: hmmmm yeah you're right. I'm calling a new instance of a class and therefore i've never manually added any accounts. I'll backtrack.

Comment: Alright yeah fixed it. If i have three items of Account I end up with these :

BankDataTypes.Account
BankDataTypes.Account
BankDataTypes.Account

using the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily just write:

```
File.WriteAllLines("SavedAccounts.txt", SavedActionList.Select(item => item.ToString()));
```

However, this will require your `Account` class to override `ToString` to provide the information you wish to write to the file.

If you don't have an overridden `ToString`, I recommend making a method to handle this:

```
string AccountToLine(Account account)
{
   // Convert account into a 1 line string, and return
}
```

With this, you could then write:

```
File.WriteAllLines("SavedAccounts.txt", SavedActionList.Select(AccountToLine));
```

---

Edit in response to comments:

> It simply doesn't work. I'm really confused as to why, which is why I posted the question. I tested it by inserting a file.WriteLine("Hello") before the file.Close() and when i run the program and check the file all it will have in it is "Hello"

This actually sounds like you're writing out your collection without adding items to it.  If the collection is empty, the above code (and yours) will create an empty file of output, as there are no `Account` instances to write out.

Comment: Thanks, got the the items successfully added into the collection and it worked with the original code after I overloaded the toString(). Thanks.